# Connecting a Spring context inside a webapp to one outside

Tags: spring

I have an application that embeds tomcat, and in the embedded tomcat, launches a webapp, and in the webapp, has a spring context.

I want to communicate a bean's worth of configuration from the application to code inside the webapp, and, if at all possible, I'd like to avoid going over JNDI falls in a barrel. So, I wonder, is there any way to get the ContextLoaderListener to connect up with an 'outer' context? Failing that, I can communicate a reference via a static field in a class that is loaded in the application's class loader and then inherited into the webapp's class loader.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just configuration from an outer bean, you can probably register a new [PropertySource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) which will pull in the configuration, Spring provides a good [Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) 
abstraction also which you can use to either pull in the configuration or even pull in an entire context information.